# Ruby Socket.IO callback

Tags: javascript, ruby, callback, socket.io

I'm using [Ruby Socket.IO client simple](https://github.com/shokai/ruby-socket.io-client-simple) and trying to replicate this JS code with Ruby with no luck. JS code is working as expected, however, Ruby version does not produce callback output 'Authentication successful' on 'auth' emit.

Although auth in Ruby is successful, since I can emit other private methods after auth. The only question is why callback doesn't work

**JS**

```
var ws = io('https://test.com')

ws.on('connect', function () {
    auth(ws, pubKey, secKey, function (err, auth) {
        if (err) return console.error('Error', err);
        if (auth.success)
            console.log('Authentication successful');
        else
            console.log('Authentication failed');
    });
});

function auth(ws, pubKey, secKey, cb) {
    var data = { apiKey: pubKey, cmd: 'getAuthInfo', nonce: Date.now() };
    var sig = crypto.sign(data, secKey);
    ws.emit('auth', data, sig, cb);
}
```

**Ruby**

```
require 'socket.io-client-simple'
require 'date'

ws = SocketIO::Client::Simple.connect 'https://test.com'

socket.on :connect do
   auth(ws, pubKey, secKey, method(:auth_callback))
end

def auth(ws, pubKey, secKey, cb)
   data = { apiKey: pubKey, cmd: 'getAuthInfo', nonce: DateTime.now }
   sig = Crypto.sign(data, secKey)
   ws.emit :auth, [data.to_json, sig, cb]
end

def auth_callback(err, auth)
   if auth.success
      puts 'Authentication successful'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auth_callback` doesn't get called because you don't call it anywhere!

You pass the method `method(:auth_callback)` as a parameter called `cb` to `auth`method, but you don't do anything with `cb`.

`cb` is a [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html), so you can use [call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-call) on it.

There's not enough data to test your code, so here's a basic example :

```
cb=3.method(:+)
cb.call(2)
#=> 5
```

`err` is neither defined nor used, so you could remove it from `def auth_callback(err, auth)`.

Comment: thanks, i see that you mean, but it looks like, I cannot actually get response of emit method in ruby, as in js. looks like it's a limitation of socket.io-client-simple wrapper